# "File is empty or corrupted" error message is getting while using MODI OCR

Tags: c#, ocr, tiff, text-extraction, modi

I want to extract text from image using

> MODI OCR

but getting error while creating MODI document.

My Code:

```
private static string Scan(string imagePath)
        {
            MODI.Document md = new MODI.Document();
            md.Create(imagePath);
            md.OCR(MODI.MiLANGUAGES.miLANG_ENGLISH, true, true);
            MODI.Image image = (MODI.Image)md.Images[0];
            MODI.Layout layout = image.Layout;
            string scanned = string.Empty;

            for (int j = 0; j < layout.Words.Count; j++)
            {
                MODI.Word word = (MODI.Word)layout.Words[j];
                string text = word.Text;
                var rect = word.Rects;
                short Confidence = word.RecognitionConfidence;
                scanned += text + " ";
            }
            md.Close(false);
            return scanned;
        }
```

I am getting run time error on `md.Create(imagePath);`
File extention is .tif and there is no issue with the image.
What will be the reason for this error and how I can solve it?

Comment: Have nothing to do with image.  Program can't create the file or create the constructor for the class.  The class is probably loading a dll and is having issue with the dll.  what using statements are at top of module?  The is issues with a reference.  The image file may not be compatible with the graphic card on your machine.  Check you card to see if it support the image mode.

Comment: Its a file path.

Comment: Which means you are reading a file.  So the file  permissions may not allow you to open the file or the image is not compatible with the MODI library.